# GET curl in php

Tags: php, curl

I have some problems while trying to do a curl to other server from my php script. Both servers are mine.

I have a servlet in java in which I can ask for some events and it works fine if I try to get data from a mobile phone or postman in chrome. It ask for 2 headers, Content-Type and Authorization.

I try to make a client in php:

```
<?php
    function get($url)
    {
     echo "start get function<br>";
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, array(
     'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8',
     'Authorization: Basic data_to_authtenticate_in_base_64'
     ));
     $response = curl_exec($ch);
     echo $response;
     curl_close($ch);
     return $response;
 }
 // Sample call
 echo "start<br>";
 get('MY URL');
 echo "end";
 ?>
```

With the same data in authorization, I get all information in postman but in php I just get nothing. I don't know how to check complete answer in php to see what is wrong. I have to do a GET. Is it everything ok in my script?

I think this script doesn't reach my other server. I just tested adding some debug lines to the second server and from Postman, it prints them but from php it doesn't. Until now, curl from php has worked fine from this server. I use it a lot in other pages. How can I check if  need to activate something?

Comment: Does it ask for 3 headers of just the two you mentioned? Your question tells both, which is (imho) impossible :)

Comment: 2 headers, Content-Type and Authorization. I always send 2 in all my queries

Comment: I updated the question, I wrote 3 instead of 2

Comment: is url HTTPS or HTTP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks ok, so use

```
curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

It will give you a verbose output of the request, so you exactly see what happens.

== Update

```
echo curl_getinfo($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';
```

You'll see what failed during your curl execution with this echo's

Comment: I just added, executed the script and I see nothing. Do I have to print it in some way?

Comment: Might want to change the echo $result to var_dump($result); and then exit before the return to get some more information.

Comment: var_dump($response); gives me "bool(false)" I also added CURLOPT_VERBOSE to true

Comment: I means that your request is not completed, you get a boolean that returns false. Will update answer.

Comment: I just figure it out what is happening. I get a "couldn't connect to host" from php

Comment: Actually, it is. But the second machine is another machine in the same network. And I am using the dns given to the first machine. From outside it works but it seems not to work from inside... I will check. Thanks for your help